# Allow Cors domain to access REST resource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm attempting to access REST resource http://localhost:4200/api/auth/signin from the browser but i wasn't able to allow origin cors domain between angular and Spring boot.

the consol shows these errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8484/api/auth/signin'
> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
> value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response
> is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is
> 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
> XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

The version of Spring security that i'm working with is 5.7.3, and it seems that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is not recommended anymore.
When i tested the ressource **../signin**  by postman it's working fine.
Here is how i proceeded, to implement  the WebSecurityConfig class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(

 prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
  @Value("${allowed.origin}")
  private String allowedOrigin ;
  @Value("${spring.h2.console.path}")
  private String h2ConsolePath;
  
  @Autowired
  UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

  @Bean
  public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
       
      authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
      authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
   
      return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
    return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }


  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(h2ConsolePath + "/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

 // fix H2 database console: Refused to display ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
  }
@Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer GetCorsConfugation(){
    return  new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigin)
                .allowedMethods("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*") ;
      }
    };
}

}
```

the Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins  = {"http://localhost:4200"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {
  @Autowired
  AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  RoleRepository roleRepository;

  @Autowired
  PasswordEncoder encoder;

  @Autowired
  JwtUtils jwtUtils;

  @PostMapping("/signin")
  public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
        .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    ResponseCookie jwtCookie = jwtUtils.generateJwtCookie(userDetails);

    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
        .body(new UserInfoResponse(userDetails.getId(),
                                   userDetails.getUsername(),
                                   userDetails.getEmail(),
                                   roles));
  }
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what to do: if you are using cookies, in your cors configuration, you have to add `registry.allowCredentials(true)`